# Jackson java.util.Optional serialization does not include type ID

Tags: spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I got the following classes:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
    property = "oid"
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "clazz")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MySubEntity.class, name = "MySubEntity"),
})
public abstract class Entity {
    ...
}

public class MySubEntity extends Entity {
    ...
}
```

Now when I serialize that `MySubEntity` wrapped in an `Optional` then JSON does not contain the `clazz` attribute containing the type ID. **Bug?** When I serialize to `List<MySubEntity>` or just to `MySubEntity` it works fine.

Setup: jackson-databind 2.9.4, jackson-datatype-jdk8 2.9.4, serialization is done in Spring Boot application providing a RESTful web service.

**EDIT:** Here is the Spring REST method that returns the `Optional`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{uuid}", produces = "application/json")
public Optional<MySubEntity> findByUuid(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
I [made a SSCCE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/719poeehq6z05ac/demo-49071166.zip?dl=0) with a simple Spring REST controller and two tests. The first test is using `ObjectMapper` directly which is successful in deserialization although the `clazz` is missing. The second test calls the REST controller and fails with an error because `clazz` is missing:

> Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.demo.MySubEntity] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.example.demo.MySubEntity]: missing type id property 'clazz'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.example.demo.MySubEntity]: missing type id property 'clazz'

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to serialize entity to JSON or to deserialize it from JSON?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I do both. My Spring REST webservice is producing JSON and my client application is consuming it. Model classes are shared between server and client.

Comment: Do you use spring-boot? Try to remove the version from dependency. Having `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent or as BOM in your `pom.xml` should resolve the right version for dependencies. With exactly the same controller the response that I'm getting is `{"clazz":"MySubEntity","oid":1}`.

Comment: Could you, please, post the `json` response that you get?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I added an SSCCE. If you have some time you can try it. Just call the test task of gradle build.

Comment: Json response is: `{"oid":1,"uuid":"1234","someProperty":"test"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, indeed, looks like a bug. There is one workaround that I can suggest for this case, is to use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` and add field `clazz` to your `Entity`. There only one case with this approach is that the `clazz` must be set in java code manually. However this is easy to overcome.
Here is the full code for suggested workaround:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
        property = "oid"
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, //field must be present in the POJO
        property = "clazz")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MySubEntity.class, name = "MySubEntity"),
})
public abstract class Entity {

    @JsonProperty
    private String uuid;

    //Here we have to initialize this field manually.
    //Here is the simple workaround to initialize in automatically
    @JsonProperty
    private String clazz = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(String clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am glad that you could confirm the bug and that you found a workaround. Thanks! I will try to open an issue on github jackson-datatype-jdk8 project.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich the `jackson-datatype-jdk8` project is deprecated and moved to `jackson-modules-java8`. However with this dependency on I can still reproduce the issue. So go ahead and open the issue! :)

Comment: @SteffenHarbich looks like there was such an issue opened here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/44